# Vee-validate: Schema validation with dynamic parames

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

i wan t to create schema validation, with dynamic params use vee-validate in vue js. but the issue is my methods and computed property be undefined in the schema.
here is my code.
`

```
export defaults {
 data() {
  const self = this;
  return {
    fixedSchema: {
        fixed: `required|min_value:0|max_value:${self.subTotal()}`,
      }
  }
},
methods: {
 subTotal() {
   return 56;
 }

}
}
```

the idea is to create validation schema with dynamic property.

Comment: Could you create some reproduction on online platform like codesandbox, etc. I'm sure it will be easy to answer once you create minimal reporduction for us

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i fixed the issue by creating a computed property that returns the schema object. so instead of declaring fixedSchema object in data property, I did it in computed property.